# Add new data to gridview without refreshing entire gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I know the title might make my question look like a duplicate so please read the complete question first.

I have 3 dropdowns in my webform and based on those parameters the data is retrieved from the database and my gridview is populated. What I need is that once a result is displayed, if the user changes the parameters, the new retrieved data should be displayed below the old data. But currently my gridview is refreshing entirely and only the data based on new parameters is displayed. 
I have read that one way is to use viewstate but I dont understand what it is. Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: This is not answer but more suggestion (i was doing that way many many years ago). Populating gridview will cause huge data load on every refresh, sometimes can slow down loading page. My suggestion will be more to change complete approach using : html table, javascript and webapi. All data will get using webapi and showing them by js.

Comment: I have data in SQL database. I am retrieving that data based on the parameters passed using dropdownlist. So I cant use API (i think).

Comment: @nelek - don't be silly here. If the api call returns a boatload of records, then you have the EXACT same problem. Pulling too much data is pulling too much data. Beyond laughable that pulling the same data via ajax calls or shoving in a data  source to  grid view will run ANY different in speed? Nope not and issue and not even helpful here. No one is suggesting that you filter against the grid data - just not done. If a large number of records is returned, then you dump the built in datapager, and use sql paging - it fine to do as such even with a GridView.

Comment: Ok, this is a VERY difficult question, since you want to be able to select multple critra - select, and then add another 100% critera and include that in the results. I have used some VERY impressive natural language query systems that allow this. This means that each filter criteria you create and make has to be saved. So, if you have 2 or 5 different filters, then you have to union all query all of the filters, and select distinct row from those multiple criteria. this can be done, but its a challenge. You not only need some UI to get a filter but also save the filter and add them up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is a difficult question. It is rather easy to filter, and have a cumulative filter.

So, say we have this screen:

[image]

And lots more rows.

So, I can say lets filter by a city.

So this:

[image]

Note how we do allow multiple city in the multi-select drop down.

So, I now have this:

[image]

Now, lets select those ONLY with a description.

So this:

[image]

And then say only active ones. So, this:

[image]

So, above is quite easy to setup. Note how any option NOT selected is left out of the critera.

but, a BIG problem exists in the above.

What happens if I want Active from say B.C. but NOT active from Alberta???

I can't do that, and hence your problem.

What we could do however is add a button to above to SAVE the resulting filter, and put the "list" of filters say into a list box or collection.

we then have a search button to search on our collection of filters.

Let me see if this can work - I'll add to above a "box" or collection of each filter.

I would think a union query with distinct row for each filter would do the trick.

So, above example is not too hard - a "cumulative" filter. In fact, the code patter for 2 or 15 filters is quite easy to do here.

However, adding up separate filter requests and combine them? That is somewhat difficult to do.

## Edit: Multiple filters

so, while in above, I could say filter by city and get all active, but THEN I want to filter by another city, and get all NON active!!!

That's the problem here.

So, we would have to add code to SAVE the filter. And the HUGE problem with that is how then do we save each filter to "add up" each filter set we want?

We could try and save the raw SQL, but such SQL would be subject to sql injection, and we want to always use parameters.

So, we can and could adopt a design in which we SAVE the resulting SqlCommand object. And then merge the results.

So, now our UI becomes like this:

Lets grab and filter all those from city Edmonton, but Active,
so, this:

[image]

We now hit save filter and this:

[image]

And now we filter by say City = Banff, but don't care about active or not.

So we have this:

[image]

We then save that filter - and now we have this:

[image]

I now hit the filter button below the list of filters, and we get this:

[image]

So, how does this code work?

Well, I simple saved the Sqlcommand object to a collection (list), and thus combine the results.

So, first our markup at the top for the filter stuff.

```
        <h4>Filters</h4>
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Search Hotel"></asp:Label>
            <br />
             <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Search City"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Must Have Description"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDescripiton" runat="server"  />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Show only Active Hotels"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActiveOnly" runat="server"  />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdSearch_Click"/>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdClear" runat="server" Text="Clear Fitler" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdClear_Click"/>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Save Filter" 
                CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdTest_Click"
                OnClientClick="return myfilterprompt()"
                />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HFilterName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
            <script>
                function myfilterprompt() {
                    sFilter = ""
                    sFilter = prompt('Enter name for filter ')
                    if ( (sFilter === null) || (sFilter === "") ){
                        return false
                    }
                    $('#HFilterName').val(sFilter)
                    return true
                }

            </script>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:30px;width:190px">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstFilters" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100px"
                DataTextField="sFilterName" >
            </asp:ListBox>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdMultiFilter" runat="server" Text="Filter" 
                CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdMultiFilter_Click" style="float:left" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdMultiClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" 
                CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdMultiClear_Click" style="float:right"/>

        </div>
```

then below above is our grid:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
            CssClass="table" Width="60%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active"  />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So, code to load:

```
    List<MyFilter> MyFilters = new List<MyFilter>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            SqlCommand cmdSQL = new
                SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = 0");

            LoadGrid(cmdSQL);
            Session["MyFilters"] = MyFilters;

        }
        else
            MyFilters = (List<MyFilter>)Session["MyFilters"];
    }

    public void LoadGrid(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

And now our search button:

```
    protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = GetMyCommand();
        LoadGrid(cmdSQL);
    }

    SqlCommand GetMyCommand()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotels ";
        string strORDER = " ORDER BY HotelName";
        string strFilter = "";

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();

        if (txtHotel.Text != "")
        {
            strFilter = "(HotelName like @HotelName + '%')";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@HotelName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtHotel.Text;
        }

        if (txtCity.Text != "")
        {
            if (strFilter != "") strFilter += " AND ";
            strFilter += "(City Like @City + '%') ";
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCity.Text;
        }

        if (chkActiveOnly.Checked)
        {
            if (strFilter != "") strFilter += " AND ";
            strFilter += "(Active = 1)";
        }
        if (chkDescripiton.Checked)
        {
            if (strFilter != "") strFilter += " AND ";
            strFilter += "(Description is not null)";
        }

        if (strFilter != "") strSQL += " WHERE " + strFilter;

        strSQL += strORDER;
        cmdSQL.CommandText = strSQL;

        return cmdSQL;
    }
```

And now our save the filter button code:

```
    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyFilter OneFilter = new MyFilter();

        OneFilter.sFilterName = HFilterName.Value;
        OneFilter.cmdSQL = GetMyCommand();

        MyFilters.Add(OneFilter);
        lstFilters.DataSource = MyFilters;
        lstFilters.DataBind();
    }

    public class MyFilter
    {
        public string sFilterName { get; set; }
        public SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();
    }
```

And our multi-filter code button.

Now, for large data sets - not a great idea, but a start:

```
    protected void cmdMultiFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<DataTable> MyTables = new List<DataTable>();
        foreach (MyFilter OneFilter in MyFilters)
        {
            DataTable rstDT = MyRstP(OneFilter.cmdSQL);
            MyTables.Add(rstDT);
        }

        DataTable rstData = MyTables[0];
        for (int i = 1;i < MyTables.Count;i++)
        {
            rstData.Merge(MyTables[i]);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

so, you can build list up of "filters" and display them in a listbox and then have a filter button that merges all of the filtering.

And one more helper routine I used:

```
    public DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

These systems can be really nice. Often a group of managers will say, lets grab all customers from west coast. Yuk - too many. Ok, only those with purchases in last 2 months - ah, that's nice.

then they say, lets get all customers who never purchased anything, but from the south - and add those to the list - but only active on our mailing list.

So, this type of slice and dice - get some of those, and then get some of these, and then combine them?

This type of business query system and being able to combine these, and those, and them, and then toss in a few more? Often they will keep going say until such time they get say 10,000 results (which happens to be how many catalogs they have left they would like to send out).

Comment: Thanks man. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: For filtering think about adding 2 parms; one LIKE and one NOT LIKE. That way it should be flexible enough to have the user filter accordingly.

Comment: see my example posted code and markup. I would of course make the city selector allow multiple cities - so a jQuery add and a multiple select drop down would be nice here. But, the above shows how we can combine multiple filters.  I now assume that if text box is empty, then we ignore that filter.  And thus for check boxes, if un-checked I get all rows - not un-checked ones only. This of course could be changed.

Comment: Hi, I tried these methods but they were not exactly working. I tried a little different techique, I posted it as an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved my problem by using a little outside the box thinking. I am posting it here for anyone visiting this question or having a same problem in the future could see this:

So what I did is that I extracted the data from the database based on the parameters selected by the user from the dropdowns. In the database, I had created a temp table to store the extracted temporarily. So I inserted the data into that temporary table and used that table to populate the gridview. I had to add a reset button, when the user clicked it the all the data is deleted from the temp table and also the page reset to its default with gridview not visible and dropdowns having no selection.

Comment: You have to also include a user name in that table, else if two people are using and viewing this data at the same time, then they will step on top of each other. Not a huge deal, but you want to keep the multi-user issue in mind.